# Displaying a Selected Location on ArcGIS Map View

Tags: arcgis-ios

I am New to ArcGIS. I am Developing an iOS application Using ArcGIS iOS SDK.

In that application i want to implement general search of an address like if I type a key word in my search field i want to display all the addresses,blocks,Highways,Avenues etc.. matching to that key word. I write the below code for implementing general search.

ViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.mapView.layerDelegate = self;
    self.mapView.callout.delegate = self;
    self.searchBar.delegate = self;
    AGSCredential* cred = [[AGSCredential alloc] initWithUser:@"username" password:@"password"];

    AGSTiledMapServiceLayer *tiledMapServiceLayer = [AGSTiledMapServiceLayer tiledMapServiceLayerWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"url"] credential:cred];
    [self.mapView addMapLayer:tiledMapServiceLayer];

    self.dynamicLayer = [[AGSDynamicMapServiceLayer alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"Dynamic Layer Ursl"] credential:cred];
    [self.mapView addMapLayer:self.dynamicLayer withName:@"POIS"];
    [self.mapView addMapLayer:self.dynamicLayer withName:@"ADDRESSES"];
    [self.mapView addMapLayer:self.dynamicLayer withName:@"HIGHWAYS"];
    [self.mapView addMapLayer:self.dynamicLayer withName:@"AVENUES"];
    [self.mapView addMapLayer:self.dynamicLayer withName:@"ROADS_LANES"];
    [self.mapView addMapLayer:self.dynamicLayer withName:@"BLOCKS"];
    [self.mapView addMapLayer:self.dynamicLayer withName:@"AREAS"];
    [self.mapView addMapLayer:self.dynamicLayer withName:@"GOVERNORATE"];

    self.graphicsLayer = [AGSGraphicsLayer graphicsLayer];
    [self.mapView addMapLayer:self.graphicsLayer withName:@"Results"];
    self.graphicsLayer.calloutDelegate = self;

    self.findTask = [[AGSFindTask alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"findTaskURL"] credential:cred];
    self.findTask.delegate = self;

    self.findParams = [[AGSFindParameters alloc]init];

}

- (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {

self.mapView.callout.hidden = YES;
self.findParams.contains = YES;
self.findParams.layerIds = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"0",@"1",@"2",@"3",@"4",@"5",@"6",@"7",nil];
self.findParams.outSpatialReference = self.mapView.spatialReference;
self.findParams.returnGeometry = TRUE;
self.findParams.searchFields = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"SearchFields",nil];
self.findParams.searchText = searchBar.text;
[self.findTask executeWithParameters:self.findParams];
[searchBar resignFirstResponder];
}
 -(void)findTask:(AGSFindTask *)findTask operation:(NSOperation *)op didExecuteWithFindResults:(NSArray *)results
{

[self.graphicsLayer removeAllGraphics];

poiArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
addressArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
highwayArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
avenueArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
roadLanesArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
blocksArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
areasArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
governarateArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

poiObjectArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
addressObjectArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
highwayObjectArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
avenueObjectArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
roadLanesObjectArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
blocksObjectArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
areasObjectArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
governarateObjectArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

AGSFindResult *result = nil;

NSMutableDictionary *d = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
NSMutableString *d1 = [[NSMutableString alloc]init];
NSMutableString *d2 = [[NSMutableString alloc]init];
NSMutableString *d3 = [[NSMutableString alloc]init];

for (int i=0;i<[results count];i++)
{
    result = [results objectAtIndex:i];
    NSDictionary *json = [result encodeToJSON];

    NSInteger i = [[json valueForKey:@"layerId"]integerValue];
    NSLog(@"%ld",(long)i);
    d = [json valueForKey:@"attributes"];

    if(i == 0)
    {
        d1 = [d valueForKey:@"NAME"];
        [poiArray addObject:d1];
        [poiObjectArray addObject:result];
        d1 = nil;
    }
    else if(i==1)
    {
        d1 = [d valueForKey:@"BUILDING NO"];
        d2 = [d valueForKey:@"BLOCK NO"];
        d3 = [d valueForKey:@"ROAD NO"];
        NSMutableString *str = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"Bul-%@,Blo-%@,Road-%@",d1,d2,d3];
        [addressArray addObject:str];
        [addressObjectArray addObject:result];
        d1=nil;
        d2=nil;
        d3=nil;
    }
    else if(i==2)
    {
        d1 = [d valueForKey:@"ROAD NAME ENGLISH"];
        d2 = [d valueForKey:@"ROAD NO"];
        NSMutableString *str = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"%@-%@",d1,d2];
        [highwayArray addObject:str];
        [highwayObjectArray addObject:result];
        d1 = nil;
        d2 = nil;
    }
    else if(i==3)
    {
        d1 = [d valueForKey:@"ROAD NAME ENGLISH"];
        [avenueArray addObject:d1];
        [avenueObjectArray addObject:result];
        d1 = nil;
    }
    else if(i==4)
    {
        d1 = [d valueForKey:@"ROAD NAME ENGLISH"];
        [roadLanesArray addObject:d1];
        [roadLanesObjectArray addObject:result];
        d1 = nil;
    }
    else if(i==5)
    {
        d1 = [d valueForKey:@"BLOCK NO"];
        [blocksArray addObject:d1];
        [blocksObjectArray addObject:result];
        NSLog(@"%@",json);

    }
    else if(i==6)
    {
        d1 = [d valueForKey:@"AREA NAME ENGLISH"];
        [areasArray addObject:d1];
        [areasObjectArray addObject:result];
        d1 = nil;
    }
    else if(i==7)
    {
        d1 = [d valueForKey:@"NAME ENGLISH"];
        [governarateArray addObject:d1];
        [governarateObjectArray addObject:result];
    }


    if ([result.feature.geometry isKindOfClass:[AGSPoint class]]) {

       AGSSimpleMarkerSymbol *symbol = [AGSSimpleMarkerSymbol simpleMarkerSymbol];
        symbol.style = AGSSimpleMarkerSymbolStyleDiamond;
        result.feature.symbol = symbol;

    }
    else if ([result.feature.geometry isKindOfClass:[AGSPolyline class]]) {
        AGSSimpleLineSymbol *symbol = [AGSSimpleLineSymbol simpleLineSymbol];
        symbol.style = AGSSimpleLineSymbolStyleSolid;
        symbol.color = [UIColor blueColor];
        symbol.width = 2;
        result.feature.symbol = symbol;

    }
    else if ([result.feature.geometry isKindOfClass:[AGSPolygon class]]) {

        AGSSimpleLineSymbol *outline = [AGSSimpleLineSymbol simpleLineSymbol];
        outline.style = AGSSimpleLineSymbolStyleSolid;
        outline.color = [UIColor redColor];
        outline.width = 2;

        AGSSimpleFillSymbol *symbol = [AGSSimpleFillSymbol simpleFillSymbol];
        symbol.outline = outline;

        result.feature.symbol = symbol;
    }
    [self.graphicsLayer addGraphic:result.feature];
  }

}
- (BOOL) callout:(AGSCallout *)callout willShowForFeature:(id<AGSFeature>)feature layer:(AGSLayer<AGSHitTestable> *)layer mapPoint:(AGSPoint *)mapPoint {
 return NO;


}

- (IBAction)list:(id)sender
{
tableViewController *tab =[[tableViewController alloc]init];
    tab.poiArray1 = poiArray;
    tab.addressArray1 = addressArray;
    tab.areasArray1 = areasArray;
    tab.governarateArray1 = governarateArray;
    tab.blocksArray1 = blocksArray;
    tab.highwayArray1 = highwayArray;
    tab.avenueArray1 = avenueArray;
    tab.roadLanesArray1 = roadLanesArray;

    tab.poiObjectArray1 = poiObjectArray;
    tab.addressObjectArray1 = addressObjectArray;
    tab.areasObjectArray1 = areasObjectArray;
    tab.governarateObjectArray1 = governarateObjectArray;
    tab.blocksObjectArray1 = blocksObjectArray;
    tab.highwayObjectArray1 = highwayObjectArray;
    tab.avenueObjectArray1 = avenueObjectArray;
    tab.roadLanesObjectArray1 = roadLanesObjectArray;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:tab animated:YES];
 }
```

By Using the above code I Was able to show all the data matching with that key word in a table View section wise.

How can I Display Only One Location on the map whatever the user selected from that table?

Answer (score 1):

Your [AGSGrapicsLayer](https://developers.arcgis.com/ios/api-reference/interface_a_g_s_graphics_layer.html) inherits from [AGSFeatureLayer](https://developers.arcgis.com/ios/api-reference/interface_a_g_s_feature_layer.html#a4366dae3afbb7a347745bc2c7296a690) which has a property definitionExpression (NString), this is a where clause, if you know what was used to select the feature then you can apply that to the definitionExpression to restrict the display to just that feature.

Comment: Can u Please give Me Some Example. i am New to ArcGIS

Comment: Sorry, I don't use this SDK. I use ArcObjects which has similarities to this. The self.graphicsLayer should have a property *definitionExpression* which you can set to a SQL query that defines the feature.